# Resize gridview for different screen sizes

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

We have a gridview with 3 col and 11 rows that contains textviews with the gridview is nested in a relativelayout. When I render the Activity on a Nexus 5X 5.2in the fit perfect. When the gridview is rendered on a Nexus S 4in screen the fit is not resizing. So my question is do I need a Fragment for just the GridView. I tried res/layout activity_page.xml as the master and activity_two.xml sw240dp and copy and pasted the master layout in the sw240dp and changed the size of the text in the textview and the width of the row example code below. At this point I am not sure this is the best way to render the text is with a gridview or do I need a Fragment and NO I do not know how to write a fragment yet. Android is seeing the two Emulators as the same size so I have a lot to learn about screen sizes and layouts.

```
    <GridLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnCalc"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="11"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="#f9f4f4"
    android:useDefaultMargins="false">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Category"
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:width="200dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:background="#6aa6f5"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="BMI range kg/m2"
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:width="180dp"
        android:background="#6aa6f5"
        />
```

Comment: What do you mean by resizing? You are giving each column an exact width, so what do you expect to happen?

Comment: @lionscribe I would say each column has an exact width based on the values set by the TextView widget width 180dp col 2 and 200dp col 1 What I want to happen is resize the GridView on various screen sizes on smaller phones the text is cut off

Comment: If it's exact size, then it will be cut off if screen is too small.

Comment: @lionscribe so you are suggesting I remove the line of code in the XML activity that says android:width="180dp" for all the textviews I will try that

Comment: @lionscribe OK I can see how that will permit dynamic rendering in different screen sizes BUT now my background color only highlights the text not the entire column the grid is set to have alternating background color for each row perhaps I am missing how to achieve this design

Comment: @lionscribe I am thinking read the width of the screen and set the width of the GridView based on the device screen width BUT this seems like the long way around Your thoughts or anyone else care to chime in

Comment: Try setting the column_weight attribute.

Comment: You can also investigate using a TanleLayout.

Comment: @lionscribe Columns do NOT have a weight attribute and a TableLayout will have the same issues what needs reset is the width of the TextView and the textsize for each textview in the gridview when a different screen is recognized I might look at scaling the widget if that is possible I can read the size of the screen and write a switch statment but that is a lot of processing power There has to be a better way

Comment: Quoting from Android Documentation:  Excess Space Distribution

As of API 21, GridLayout's distribution of excess space accomodates the principle of weight. In the event that no weights are specified, the previous conventions are respected and columns and rows are taken as flexible if their views specify some form of alignment within their groups.

Comment: As for my comment about TableLyout, TableLyout have a TableRow for each row, so you can set the background to the TableRow, which will effect the entire row..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@James_Duh here is some code that will work but I do not feel this is the most elegant way to deal with your question. My concern is how much overhead in terms of processing power and time this method uses. Also what is the impact on memory? I do not have the ability to answer these concerns perhaps another user will expand on these questions. I would like to know how to do this by changing the properties of the GridView or utilize the styles. My solution has the potential to create a lot of code for a larger project. That said here is the code listed for your pleasure
`public class PageThree extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Button button;
TextView TVinfo;
TextView TVone, TVtwo;
RelativeLayout RLpage3;
TextView tv1,tv2,tv3,tv4,tv5,tv6;
//GridView GVtext;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_page_three );

    button = (Button) findViewById( R.id.button );
    TVinfo = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.TVinfo );
    TVone = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.TVone );
    TVtwo = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.TVtwo );
    RLpage3 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById( R.id.RLpage3 );
    tv1 = (TextView)findViewById( R.id.tv1 );
    tv2 = (TextView)findViewById( R.id.tv2 );
    tv3 = (TextView)findViewById( R.id.tv3 );
    tv4 = (TextView)findViewById( R.id.tv4 );
    tv5 = (TextView)findViewById( R.id.tv5 );
    tv6 = (TextView)findViewById( R.id.tv6 );
    //GVtext = (GridView)findViewById( R.id.GVtext );


    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int DeviceTotalWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
    int dens = metrics.densityDpi;
    int dp = (DeviceTotalWidth * 160/dens);
    TVtwo.setText( String.valueOf( DeviceTotalWidth +" "+dens +" "+ dp) );
    int dpL = dp ;
    int dpR = dp ;
    int ts = 0;
    String L = String.valueOf( dpL+"sp" );
    TVone.setText( L );

    if (DeviceTotalWidth == 480) {
        if (dp == 320) {
            dpL = 240;
            dpR = 200;
            ts = 14;
        }
    }

    if (DeviceTotalWidth == 768) {
        if (dp == 384) {
            dpL = 360;
            dpR = 360;
            ts = 20;
        }
    }
    if (DeviceTotalWidth == 1080) {
        if (dp == 411) {
            dpL = 520;
            dpR = 550;
            ts = 20;
        }
    }
    if (DeviceTotalWidth == 1536) {
        if (dp == 768) {
            dpL = 740;
            dpR = 790;
            ts = 20;
        }
    }
            TVone.setTextSize( 16 );
            tv1.setTextSize( ts );
            tv2.setTextSize( ts );
            tv3.setTextSize( ts );
            tv4.setTextSize( ts );
            tv5.setTextSize( ts );
            tv6.setTextSize( ts );
            tv1.setWidth( dpL );
            tv2.setWidth( dpR );
            tv3.setWidth( dpL );
            tv4.setWidth( dpR );
            tv5.setWidth( dpL );
            tv6.setWidth( dpR );

        }`
```